# Generate GLTF animation from separate GLTF files

Tags: gltf

I am dealing with GLTF models and I can play some animation in one program but currently it does not support saving it as single GLTF file. However I can save every frame as separate GLTF file and hopefully generate animation using them. For every such file mesh topology is exactly the same, the difference only in mesh deformation. But I can't find any description on how to do that or if such thing is possible at all.

Can someone please suggest source where I can read about similar or related topics?

thanks